# QueryableState Flink AWS EMR

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have a use-case of using Queryable state feature in an Apache Flink cluster. 
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html#activating-queryable-state

I do not want to setup my own cluster (but want to leverage existing managed solutions).

I am evaluated two possibilities: using AWS Kinesis Data Application(KDA) or using AWS EMR.

It seems that KDA does not support queryable state.

I am not sure if EMR supports that or not.  Documentation in this regards is non-existent.

Can someone please share some information on this?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling queryable state requires some configuration, which mostly involves exposing certain ports. EMR doesn't prevent you from doing this -- you can do a thoroughly custom Flink installation on EMR if you want/need to.

Another approach you might want to consider would be to use Ververica Platform's community edition on EKS. See https://www.ververica.com/blog/announcing-ververica-platform-community-edition and https://docs.ververica.com/v2.1/installation/hosted_k8s_quickstart/aws_eks.html. With this solution you will get a fully managed Flink environment that includes an option for enabling queryable state with each deployment (this option is part of the advanced configuration section).